# Can i cache the result of a geoprocess on the ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, cache

I have several geoprocessing services on my ArcGIS server:

1. baseGeoService
2. geoService1
3. geoService2

Services #2 and #3 take as input the output of baseGeoService, therefore i would like to be able to cache the result of baseGeoService on the server so the client won't have to send the result of baseGeoService to the server.

I access the services via the rest API.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do would be long and involved development. Here's some high level points you'd have to consider.

ArcGIS Server has a cleanup setting which removes files based on the last time they were accessed. You'd probably need to increase this time to something reasonable amount of time that a user may come back to your site and want to get a result back.

You'd need to implement some sort of "sessions". Perhaps using cookies? Or you could build some sort of user-login experience and track what a user does. Each GP execution gets assigned a job-id. You could use this jobid to go back and look for a result.

99% of the work would be done in your client app (maybe 100%) in creating this session and ability to go retrieve a result. There is nothing in the gp server itself to remember what user ran what task and when. You'd need logic here to get the result or create a new one when the user comes back. (these are just implementation details on your whole workflow)

Comment: i was thinking of giving the client an id to send with his next requests and then on the server side check if the file still exists, it seems from your answer that any file i save on the server will be erased automatically after some time, effectively acting as the cache i wanted. why would this be such long development? it seems just sending another parameter from the client, and on the server checking if it exists.